# How do I modify TIFF physical resolution metadata

Tags: python, tiff

I have several pyramidal, tiled TIFF images that were converted from a different format. The converter program wrote incorrect data to the XResolution and YResolution TIFF metadata. How can I modify these fields?

```
tiff.ResolutionUnit: 'centimeter'
tiff.XResolution: '0.34703996762331574'
tiff.YResolution: '0.34704136833246829'
```

Ideally I would like to use Python or a command-line tool.

Comment: Thanks @cgohlke. I love tifffile. Thanks so much for developing it. I often use the Tifffile loader in kitware’s Large Image package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use `tifftools.tiff_set` from [Tiff Tools](https://github.com/DigitalSlideArchive/tifftools).

```py
import tifftools

tifftools.tiff_set(
    PATH_TO_ORIG_IMAGE,
    PATH_TO_NEW_IMAGE,
    overwrite=False,
    setlist=[
        (
            tifftools.Tag.RESOLUTIONUNIT,
            tifftools.constants.ResolutionUnit.CENTIMETER.value,
        ),
        (tifftools.Tag.XRESOLUTION, xresolution),
        (tifftools.Tag.YRESOLUTION, yresolution),
    ],
)
```

Replace `xresolution` and `yresolution` with the desired values. *These values must be floats*. In this example, the resolution unit is centimeter.

---

This is also possible with the excellent `tifffile` package. In fact there is [an example of this use case](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile#examples) in the README.

```py
with TiffFile('temp.tif', mode='r+') as tif:
    _ = tif.pages[0].tags['XResolution'].overwrite((96000, 1000))
```

Be aware that this will overwrite the original image. If this is not desired, make a copy of the image first and then overwrite the tags.